# XSD "one or both" choice does not work with type restriction

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create an XSD where an Item needs to specify at least one identifier, or both, but never none.
This works fine in the first moment:

```
<xs:choice>
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="OneIdType">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AnotherIdType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="AnotherIdType" type="xs:string"/>
```

But both IdTypes should have (different) length restrictions.
So when I try the following my XSD is invalid:

```
<xs:choice>
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="OneIdType">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AnotherIdType" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="AnotherIdType">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I get the error

> Element   '   AnotherIdType   '    is not consistent with element     '   AnotherIdType   '   .

So is there a possibility in XSD to implement an "one or both choice" with restricted types?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the anonymous types within those two `AnotherIdType` element declarations have the same definition, they are not the *same type*.  Pull out the `simpleType` declaration to the top level

```
<xs:simpleType name="max20String">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and then reference it from both elements

```
<xs:choice>
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="OneIdType">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AnotherIdType" type="tns:max20String" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="AnotherIdType" type="tns:max20String"/>
```

(where the `tns` prefix is bound to the schema's `targetNamespace`)

Comment: Yes, and try to avoid naming *elements* with a `Type` suffix.

Comment: Thanks, Ian, that worked. The "Types" were just examples here. In my real XSD they have better names.